# iOS - App To Change Aspect Ratio of a Video

Tags: software-recommendation, aspect, ios

I'm a new iOS user, and previously on my Android device, from time to time I needed to change the aspect ratio of a video to 1:1 (to fit with Instagram).

So at that time, I was using this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.silentlexx.ffmpeggui&hl=fr) that let's you directly type ffmpeg commands as if you were using a computer, so I it was simple to do it by using :

```
-vf "scale=720:720,setsar=1:1"
```

But unfortunately I didn't find any alternative on iOS.

So, does anyone know an app that will let me change the aspect ratio of a video?

Comment: why not just go back to Android tbh? iOS doesn't have any real benefits

Comment: I  was in need of a good 4 inch smartphone.
I had to choose between an Xperia Compact and the SE, but I didn't liked the design of the Xperia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Videon**

It's a great app for the iPhone.

Not only does it have some great camera features; like stabilization, and manual exposure/WB, but you can also use it's post feature on any clip in your Photos folder.

You can crop, change aspect ratio, framerate, adjust rotation, pretty much anything... along with a ton of filters; color correcting tools and so on.

Very easy to use. And real time playback of your file as you correct it.

When finished, you can output your file by exporting it to a variety of bitrates and sizes.

A must have!

Comment: Seems great, even though it's a paid app.
By the way I discovered that a version of ffmpeg is available for iOS, but it requires to have a jailbroken iphone.